# How to send LOCAL image using javascript and receive it in PHP

Tags: javascript

We have a local system and I want to make a page that pulls an image ('http://localhost/system_analysis.png') from it and send to a php script.

I have this code which is using the FileReader class:

```
function fileAsDataURL(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     return (reader.result;
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     return 0;
   };
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", MY_API, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    value: fileAsDataURL('http://localhost/system_analysis.png')
}));
```

I tried it but I couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, simply you should think of it in two steps:

1. Converting your image to a base64 string.
2. Sending it to a PHP API which will handle the request and convert the string back to a normal image file.

**1. The file which will be run on the local server:**

*A. Converting the image to a base64 string:*

```
function fileAsDataURL(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status == 200){
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        callback(reader.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    } else callback(0);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();
}
```

*B. Function to post the base64 string to your API:*

```
function sendImg(name, value) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", 'http://YOUR_API_SERVER_HERE', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
      name: name,
      value: value
  }))
}
```

*C. Calling function `fileAsDataURL` and passing the result to function `sendImg`:*

```
fileAsDataURL('http://localhost/system_analysis.png', function(dataUrl) {
  sendImg('system_analysis.png', dataUrl);
});
```

**2. The API file:**

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$entityBody = json_decode($entityBody);

$data = explode(',', $entityBody->value);
file_put_contents('PATH_TO_SAVE_IMAGE/'.$entityBody->name, base64_decode($data[1]));
```